# I am trying to produce adjusted p-values for 119 models that were produced with lapply in R

Tags: r, loops

I produced 119 logistic regression models with lapply. I then used lapply again to get the coefficients and p-values in a summary format

```
#Model 1
#looping through the different metabolites to produce over 100 logistic 
regression models. For hpresponse1. Minimally adjusted
response1minadj<-lapply(metabolite.names, function(X) 
glm(as.formula(paste0("hpresponse1~",X, "+ age + BMIfactor")),
                                           data=df, family="binomial"))
response1minadj
#getting the effects sizes and p-values- hpresponse1, minimally adjusted
results1<-lapply(response1minadj, function(p) coef(summary(p)))
results1
```

Now I want adjusted p-values with p.adjust. I thought I could change the summary of results into their own separate dataframes, name the columns and then use p.adjust on the column I named "pvalue"

```
#changing the results into separate dataframes
results1 = lapply(results1, function (d) as.data.frame(d))

#renaming the columns
results =lapply(results1, function(b) colnames(b) = c("beta","SE", "zvalue" 
,"pvalue"))
```

However, the column names change doesn't seem to work as the following syntax produces "null"

```
colnames(results1)
```

Is there another way to accomplish my goal of getting adjusted p-values for all 119 models? Or is there a way to get my syntax to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in `lapply` returns column names, not the updated value of `b`.

Try this instead:

```
results = lapply(results1, function(b){colnames(b) = c("beta", "SE", "zvalue", "pvalue"); return(b);})
```

Comment: This still returns "Null" when I use this code you sent and then run "colnames(results1)". Could the issue be with the first part of the syntax when I turn the model results into dataframes?

Comment: Okay, so that method actually seemed to work, even if "colnames(results1)" doesn't return the column names. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For getting the p-value from the model, you can use:

```
p_values <- coef(summary(model))[, "Pr(>|t|)"]
```

For the whole list of p-values, or add [1/2/3/4/...] for a specific p-value at the end of the code.

Then you could possibly do p.adjust on p_values, e.g.,

```
p_adjusted <- p.adjust(p_values)
```

So to first get the p-value from the model, and then do p.adjust on that p-value